# How can I use custom rating for woocommerce Products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have Avada Theme installed for WooCommerce. I want to change the star rating for products. They have given options to select stars. But I would like to change the way they have implemented it. I want it to be in single row like *****. If the user click on first star it would be 1 star, if they clicked on 5th star that would be 5 star. I am providing my html for it.

```
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' ) {
                        $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating 5"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
                            <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                            <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        </select></div>';
                    }
```

I have tried this code from functions.php, which is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_print_stars' );


function my_print_stars(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
    AND meta_value > 0
");

$rating = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
");

if ( $count > 0 ) {

    $average = number_format($rating / $count, 2);

    echo '<div class="starwrapper" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';

    echo '<span class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__('Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce'), $average).'"><span style="width:'.($average*16).'px"><span itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</span> </span></span>';

    echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

But this is doing nothing. I actually want to add a star rating instead of that five option star rating. I am noob in Woocommerce, please help me in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: Otherwise if somebody can help me in getting the page where stars rating are collected and inserted into the database...so that I can write my own query.